# Combine two queries and also weight to a column using FREETEXTTABLE?

Tags: sql-server, freetexttable

I have these two queries that give me what I want:

1)

```
SELECT sr.ServicesResourcesID AS ID, sr.Title, sr.ContactFirstName, sr.ContactLastName, sr.ContactEmail, sr.ContactPhone, sr.FileName, sr.URL, sr.Description AS Description, rt.Type, KEY_TBL.RANK 
FROMvResourceType rt,vServicesResources sr
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(ServicesResources, Title, 'computers') AS KEY_TBL
ON sr.ServicesResourcesID = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
WHERE sr.ResourceTypeID = rt.ResourceTypeID
ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

2)

```
SELECT sr.ServicesResourcesID AS ID, sr.Title, sr.ContactFirstName, sr.ContactLastName, sr.ContactEmail, sr.ContactPhone, sr.FileName, sr.URL, sr.Description AS Description, rt.Type, KEY_TBL.RANK 
FROMvResourceType rt,vServicesResources sr
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(ServicesResources, Description, 'computers') AS KEY_TBL
ON sr.ServicesResourcesID = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
WHERE sr.ResourceTypeID = rt.ResourceTypeID
ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

They are basically the same query.  One searches the title, the other, the description.
I'd like to combine them AND give more weight to the Title.

Any ideas?  TIA.

Comment: I ended up using UNION to combine them and then, KEY_TBL.RANK * 2.0 AS RANK for title and KEY_TBL.RANK * 1.0 AS RANK for Description.  Seems to work.